# Adding missing records from another columns in a different table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have 2 tables :

Table A:

```
    A | B | C   |  D
   qwe  4  2019   10
   qwe  2  2020   5
   qwe  5  2019   5
```

Table B :

```
A | B 
3  2019
4  2019
5  2019
6  2019
7  2019
8  2019
9  2019
10 2019
11 2019
12 2019
1  2020
2  2020
```

I want the output table to contain all numbers and years from table B in Table A. So, the text qwe should be shown 12 times with respective numbers.

Output Table:

```
A  | B | C  | D
qwe  3  2019  0
qwe  4  2019  10
qwe  5  2019  5
qwe  6  2019  0
qwe  7  2019  0
qwe  8  2019  0
qwe  9  2019  0
qwe 10 2019   0
qwe 11 2019   0
qwe 12 2019   0
qwe 1  2020   0
qwe 2  2020  5
```

Note: Table A contains more values than qwe so i am trying to replicate 12 values for all of the different records. Column D should be showing 0 for records that dont exist.

I have tried a full outer join but a full outer join produces 12 records for each record of qwe in table A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about cross join

```
     with cte as
(
select 'qwe' as A, 4 as B, 2019 as C, 10 as D
union all
select 'qwe',2,2020,5
union all
select 'qwe',5,2019,5
),
cte1 as
(
select 3 as A, 2019 as B union all
select 4 , 2019 union all
select 5 , 2019 union all
select 6,  2019 union all
select 7,  2019 union all
select 8,  2019 union all
select 9,  2019 union all
select 10,  2019 union all
select 11,  2019 union all
select 12,  2019 union all
select 1,  2020 union all
select 2,  2020 
)
  , cte3 as
  (select distinct a.A,b.A  as B,b.B as c 
   from cte1 b cross join (select A from cte) a
   ) select distinct t1.*,coalesce(t2.D,0) as D from cte3 t1 left join cte t2 
    on t1.A=t2.A and t1.C=t2.C and t1.B=t2.B
```

output

```
 A  B    c      D
qwe 3   2019    0
qwe 4   2019    10
qwe 5   2019    5
qwe 6   2019    0
qwe 7   2019    0
qwe 8   2019    0
qwe 9   2019    0
qwe 10  2019    0
qwe 11  2019    0
qwe 12  2019    0
qwe 1   2020    0
qwe 2   2020    5
```

Comment: Cross join gives the same issue as the full outer join. Gives more records as it is a cartesian product.

Comment: @Rahul check the eidted answer please it is showing your expected output

Comment: Please take the Column D into account as well

Comment: Yes sir. I got the last join after the distinct got me the required result! thanks!! :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189910/discussion-between-zaynul-abadin-tuhin-and-rahul).

Answer (score 0):

The final column is easy . . . `left join`:

```
select b.a, b.b, coalesce(a.d, 0) as d
from b left join
     a
     on b.a = a.b and b.b = a.c;
```

The first column doesn't really make sense but perhaps:

```
select max(a.a) over () as a,
       b.a as b, b.b as c, coalesce(a.d, 0) as d
from b left join
     a
     on b.a = a.b and b.b = a.c;
```

Comment: Still only gives me the 3 columns

Comment: @Rahul . . . The second query is selecting four columns, not three.

Comment: I meant "gives me 3 records". Sorry

Comment: @Rahul . . . `b` has twelve records.  Nothing is being filtered.  The `join` is an outer join.  This should return at least 12 records.